# widely held as someone -- meaning

Tags: meaning

I'm seeing the Coach Carter movie and there is a phrase that I didn't understand. Context:

Reporter is talking

> St.Francis High School basketball phenomen. Ty Crane, who they
>   recruited just last year is widely held as the next LeBron James.

What does widely held mean here?

Comment: US sports reporters/commentators aren't *widely held **to be*** exemplars of current "standard" English, as [this chart shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=widely+held+as+the%2Cwidely+held+to+be+the&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwidely%20held%20as%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwidely%20held%20to%20be%20the%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers What do you mean  "standard" English? Everyone understand what they say...

Comment: *As my linked chart shows*, your cited usage (with *held **as*** rather than *held **to be***) is effectively "non-standard". Obviously even non-native speakers can easily understand the intended meaning, assuming they already know *to hold [some assertion] = to believe and promote [that assertion]*, But *syntactically* it's not the way the vast majority of [careful] native speakers would put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hold, definition 8: "Hold" can mean to assert, affirm, or regard in a certain way. That is, if you say, "I hold Bob to be an honest man", that means that you believe he is honest or you consider him to be honest.

If something is "widely held", that means that many people affirm or believe it.

So to say that this person is "widely held to be a great basketball player" would mean that many people consider him to be a great basketball player.

Lebron James is a well-known basketball player. So "widely held to be the next LeBron James" means "many people believe that he will become as great a basketball player as LeBron James".

(Or maybe in context they're talking about some other aspect of LeBron James. I'm not a sports fan and I don't know anything about the man, so if he's also famous for his charitable work or singing ability or whatever, it's possible that that's what they're talking about. But from the fact that the paragraph is talking about basketball, I'd guess not.)

Comment: Could we just say __Ty Crane, who they recruited just last year is held as the next LeBron James.__ without widely. I mean would it have the same meaning? Or widely adds some emphasize (__hold__ is weaker than __widely hold__ in that sense).

Comment: @DmitryFucintv "Widely held" gives the impression that more people are of that opinion as compared to just "held".

Comment: @Dmitry: *A is widely held to be B* is pretty much a "fixed expression". In fact, if you drop *widely* it would probably be understood to mean *held **by everyone***, but that's secondary to the fact that very often it would just appear "odd".

Comment: Usually if you say "held" in this sense, you have to specify by whom. You could say, "I hold that ..." or "Democrats hold that ...", or more vaguely "Many people hold that ...", etc. If you just said, "It is held that ...", the subject becomes unclear. It may be obvious from context or it may not. This isn't just true of the word "held", it applies whenever you use a passive voice. That's why politicians love the passive voice, like the classic "Mistakes were made" acknowledges a problem while neatly avoiding admitting that it was the speaker who made the mistakes.

Comment: Jay, if I say *"Newton is held to be the greatest scientist who ever lived"* surely you'd take the "missing holders" to mean ***everyone** [whose opinion is important in this context]*. It seems to me omitting ***widely*** there is inherently a more grandiose/emphatic way of putting it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If I read "Newton is held to be ..." without any context specifying who is doing the holding, I suppose I'd take that to mean that there's some general consensus. In real life I'd doubt that it means literally everyone agrees, or you wouldn't say "held", you'd just say "is". But whatever. I don't think we have a serious disagreement here.

Comment: Point taken. Until I just read your comment I hadn't consciously registered that simply using the word ***held*** at all implies we're talking about something that must to some extent be a matter of opinion, otherwise we'd obviously use an unqualified copula. (I never heard anyone say *One and one is [widely] held to be two*, for example! :)